# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & number'. ts(2322)

Tags: typescript

I'm new at typescript and trying to figure out how to handle this error. I understand why it happens, but can't find the right way to handle this

```js
type Data = {
    name: string
    age: number
}

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]

const data: Data = {
    name: 'Jack',
    age: 33,
}

function change(name: keyof Data, value: ValueOf<Data>): ValueOf<Data> {
    data[name] = value // error
    return data[name]
}
```

**Error**:

> Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string & number'.
>
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & number'.
>
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code does not work involves a little understanding of the type system.

While the expression `data[name]` in your code is of type `string | number`, any value assigned to this expression must be assignable to *both* `string` *and* `number`, or type `string & number`. This is clearly impossible.

In order to resolve this problem, `change()` should be a generic function, which would allow you to constrain the types of `data[name]` and `value`, based on the specific value of `name`:

```
type Data = {
  name: string
  age: number
}

const data: Data = {
  name: 'Jack',
  age: 33,
}

function change<K extends keyof Data>(name: K, value: Data[K]): Data[K] {
  return data[name] = value
}

change('name', 'Jill') // infers change<'name'>, value: string
change('age', 21) // infers change<'age'>, value: number
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!